# how to link a html served from a finch/finagle to a fastopt.js on script tag

Tags: scala.js

I am new to scalajs, I have a finch endpoint in my backend project serving a scalatag html generated from frontend project

```
     val apiEndpoints: Endpoint[Response] = get("index") {
val res = Response()
res.setContentString(scalaTagUI.toString())
Future(res)
```

}

in my Html I have the script tag

```
script(attr("type"):="text/javascript", attr("src"):="./target/scala-2.12/classes/assets/frontend-jsdeps.js")
```

The /index is working but it can't access the javascript files giving 404 - I can see the fastopt.js in my target/scala-2.12.....

Comment: This is really a finch/finagle question.  I don't know that server, but the Scala.js file is no different from any other JavaScript file at this point...

Answer (score 0):

The solution at the end was simple - I have added a specific endpoint in finch exclusively for js/css files. Differently if you use something like jetty you would add a folder like "webapp" containing js/css to your server context. 
Anyway It works now but I wonder if is there a different maybe cleaner approach.